# Open URL with Google Chrome from command-line with a specific profile

Tags: google-chrome

How to open an URL with Google Chrome from command-line with a specific profile?

I've so far come up with the following but the `--args --profile-directory="Profile 22"` part does not seem to pass the argument to Google Chrome:

```
open -a 'Google Chrome' https://www.bing.com --args --profile-directory="Profile 22"
```

The `-g` option is intended to not bring the Google Chrome window immediately to the foreground. C.f. the documentation for `open`:

```
-g  Do not bring the application to the foreground.
```

The following does work, but I'm trying to avoid using specific full path for Google Chrome:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --profile-directory="Profile 22" 'https://www.bing.com'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use. e.g.:

```
open -na 'Google Chrome' --args --profile-directory="Profile 22" 'https://www.bing.com'
```

However, not with the `-g` *option*.

The `-n` *option* is used to ensure opening the given *profile* if another *profile* already has a *window* open.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without bringing the activated window into focus/front?

Comment: Or perhaps immediately switch the focus back to the tab that was in focus after opening the new tab?